# Is this OOD implemented correctly?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I am learning OO SOLID principles and design patterns and I want to do some practice on it. So I get the one problem from my ongoing project and try to design it. Please check whether it is implemented correctly or it's over-engineered or I implement it poorly. Your response is most important.

**Problem**
I have to manage sms and email campaigns in one system. I meant to say storing it in database and retrieving it etc.

So I think there will be something specific to the Campaign like created date status etc. Thus I have made the class named campaignmodel which is responsible for some common functions related to campaign

```
Class CampaignModel
{
    public function save($data)
    {
        // add campaign specific data
        // save the campaign.

    }

    public function get()
    {
        // select the row from database and return it.

    }
}
```

then I make smscampaign and email campaign

```
class SMSCampaignModel extends CampaignModel
{
    public function save($data)
    {
        // add sms specific data and
        parent::save($data);
    }

    public function gets()
    {
        //fire the query to get the sms campaigns and returns it.
    }
}

class EmailCampaignModel extends CampaignModel
{
    public function save($data)
    {
        // add email  specific data
        parent::save($data);
    }

    public function gets()
    {
        //fire the query to get the email campaigns and returns it.
    }

}
```

Now every campaign will have recipients and we have to store each recipient's status like he opens mail or mail/sms sent or failed etc. I think we will send the campaigns with many emails or numbers so I decided to create different database table for storing such details such as sms_campaign_log, email_campaign_log etc. I have created the interface for it

```
interface CampaignLogs
{
    function insert_log();
    function get_details();
}

class SmsCampaignLogs implements CampaignLogs
{
    public function insert_log($data)
    {
        // get the number and status save it into the sms logs table.
    }

    public function get_details($campagin_id)
    {
        // get the logs from campagin table and return it.
    }
}

class EmailCampaignLogs implements CampaignLogs
{
    public function insert_log($data)
    {
        // get the number and status save it into the email logs table.
    }

    public function get_details($campagin_id)
    {
        // get the logs from campagin table and return it.
    }
}
```

and lastly I think now I should use strategy pattern to implement it(I don't know whether it is correct or not).

```
class Campaign
{
    private $log;
    private $campaign_type;
    public function __construct($campaign, $logger)
    {
        $this->campaign_type = $campaign;
        $this->log  = $logger;
    }

    public function save($data)
    {
        $this->campagin_type->save();

    }
    public function gets()
    {
        $this->campaign_type->gets();
    }

    public function log($data)
    {
        $this->log->insert_log($data);
    }

    public function get_campaign_details($campaign_id)
    {
        $this->log->get_details($campaign_id);
    }
}
```

now Implementation code.

```
$campaign = new SmCampaignModel();
$logger = new SmsCampaignLogs();
$c = new Campaign($campagin,$logger);
$c->save($data);
$c->get($campaign_id);
$c->get_campaing_details();
```

Then I think if strategy pattern needed.
Simply, I can implement:

```
    $campaign = new SmCampaignModel();
    $logger = new SmsCampaignLogs();
    $campaign->save($data);
    $campaign->get($campaign_id);
    $logger->get_campaing_details($campaign_id);
```

So I am now totally confused. I want your opinion on whether I applied SOLID principles correctly in my design (and strategy pattern is needed/used properly) or not.

Comment: then can we transfer this question to that site or i want to rewrite this question there @deceze

Comment: This question looks like a very stripped down "bare-bones" version of the actual code. As such it's "pseudo"- or hypothetical code and **off-topic** for codereview.se

Comment: @Siddhesh migration is possible, but requires moderator intervention and is only necessary if helpful answers/comments were given. You might as well speed things up and publish it there by yourself then delete this one.

Comment: @deceze: stop trying to shoehorn questions into CR. If this question is off-topic here, then vote to close it for *proper, listed reasons*. You can *advise* that a question might be a good CR fit, but the first rule of voting to close a post is that it has to *actually be off-topic here*. You are abusing the custom close reasons.

Comment: @deceze: for example, this question might be *too broad*. At which point you vote to close it as such, advise the OP that it might be a better fit for CR (check their on-topic help info first) and flag the post to ask a moderator to migrate it. But don't abuse the custom close vote messages for this.

Comment: The last line of your question is asking for opinions. The title of the question is difficult to answer correctly. This question is too broad. Perhaps programmers.stackexchange.com as it's more of a "white board" question than a "keyboard" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case your Campaign class is only a Facade. No Strategy is in use.

You are actually using the Facades pattern and not the Strategy. Your Campaign class doesn't have a behavior of it own. It merely delegates its behavior to subsystem components. It is not a bad thing, but it makes your code somehow harder to maintain. It is fine in terms of information hiding.

There is not right or wrong in the aspect of OOD. Design patterns are not must to be included if no reason is presented. You should ask yourself: "What is my main problem, and does this solve it?". "Will there be a reason to the code to be changed often?".

Because we are all sometimes tempted to overuse design patterns, I would like to show you how making a simple OO relationship will do just fine, and will even be easier to read and maintain.

```
abstract class Campaign {

    protected $ages;
    protected $countries;
    protected $dailyBudget;

    protected $recipientsStatus = array(); // associative array or a composition of Recipients object

    public function startCampaign()
    {
        // check there is not another run
        $this->executeCampaign();
        $this->collectRecipientsStatus();
        $this->generateStatistics();
    }

    abstract protected function executeCampaign();
    abstract protected function collectRecipientsStatus();
    abstract protected function generateStatistics();

}

class EmailCampaign extends Campaign {

    protected $addresses;

    protected function executeCampaign()
    {
        $this->filterEmailsByCampaignData();
        $this->sendEmails();
    }

    protected function filterEmailsByCampaignData()
    {
        // populate $this->addresses based on ages, countries etc.
    }

    protected function sendEmails()
    {
        // send email to addresses
    }

    protected function collectRecipientsStatus()
    {
        // collect status and fill parent $recipientsStatus
    }

    protected function generateStatistics()
    {
        // generate statistics
    }
}
```

Campaign now is a class with data and behavior. We don't have to decouple it into components like Model and Logs. This will work just fine. However, if you ever find yourself with a bit more complicated Recipients array (too many key values or dimensional array code smells), then you might decouple it into another set of classes. But this should happen with evolution of the code. We simply cannot foresee everything in advance.

By the way, the only pattern I used is the lightweight Template Method, and inheritance feature of OOP.

Comment: but sir @techwisdom you are merging all campaign functionality into one class so SRP will be break. also if I change the email sending library or anything else It will also break open closed principle? i think so.

Comment: and sir code is looking as strategy pattern which i have learned using 'head first design patterns' duck example.

Comment: @Siddhesh, First of all, the appearance is not an indicator for a pattern. Actually, there are different patterns which their OO structure / UML are the *same*: State, Strategy, Bridge and somehow Adapter are implemented exactly the same. The only difference is the intent and their nature. It is not *how* they solve the problem, but *why*. You are right, SRP and atomicity are important. But all I can see now is the Campaign class only starts campaigns based on its data. This is a singular functionality. I split away the CRUD (db) operations because it doesn't have to be the task of the class.

Comment: @Siddhesh, As I wrote previously: there is not right or wrong. Actually you made a great job with the code you wrote. Head first is a good start and I can tell you did well. My focus was to show you that sometimes simplicity wins. You showed a good solution, but my only doubt is whether this solution would help you with the current requirements you are facing with your project. But if you only tried to practice on design patterns, keep doing this. You'll collect efficient tools to help yourself later on.

Comment: So We should use the patterns when we stuck at something with oo right?

Comment: Patterns are just known recipes written by others to solve common problems. You can invent your own recipe or adjust the existing to your case. Usually they make the code-base easier to maintain, read, be tested and extended with minimal risk of jeopardizing the entire platform.

Comment: But sir I really think so maintaining campaign and maintaing reciepents status (i.e i have used logger into my post) both are the seperate thing bcoz when saving the campaign i just store the recps groups we can't store the thousands contacts at a time but when we are sending the email to each reciepents we will store the status message failed / succeed etc. what do you think. both shoud be seperate class they used by different client code.

Comment: Pay attention I said you could use a composition of Recipients inside the Campaign class instead of an associative array. But the reason should not be your intent to save a delta of the data ("groups"). Instead,  even with a recipients  array, you can change your OO logic to relate to each campaign as a combination of properties and a bulk timestamp. That means any particular campaign might have several instances in each different recipients and a different timestamp. Maybe use the instance fields: $currentBulkRecipients, $currentBulkTimestamp and $totalRecipients. The latter wouldn't be saved

Comment: I m really sorry but I am not getting you what you say. please explain it. I will tell you my thinking before sending bulk campaign user should create a list which have contacts when saving campaign I just saved group ids and when executing campaign I am saving the actual contact for the campaign with it's status bcoz if user deleted the list I have access to the campaign contacts just like product logic in shopping cart at order we save the product price and details at particular order. Are you saying me to  do something more better. then I am interested Bcoz I like improvement.